# How do I import certain columns from a csv file into mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, csv, import

I'm not sure if I should ask this in ServerFault or here, but I'm trying to write a PHP script that loops through a folder and adds csv files to a mongodb database.

I'd only like to import certain fields/columns. Is that possible, or do I need to import the whole table/collection, then drop fields? Google doesn't seem to be helping...

Comment: Why don't you try --fields option of mongoimport ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17284241/162228) helpful. The OP there was attempting to do the same thing.

The [mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) command doesn't give you the option of skipping fields during the import process, so that would require a full import followed by `$unset` operations on the fields you intended to omit. Ultimately, that would leave your collection with fragmentation.

You would be better served using [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) or [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) in PHP to parse the file. This would also allow you the change to validate/sanitize the input as necessary. Finally, [MongoCollection::batchInsert()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.batchinsert.php) would efficiently insert multiple documents into MongoDB at once.