# MongoDB php driver, script ends when inserting data

Tags: php, mongodb, csv

Im playing with MongoDB and Im trying to import .csv files to DB and Im getting strange error. In process of uploading script just ends for no reason and when I try to run it again nothing happens only solution is to restart apache. I have already set unlimited timeout in php.ini Here is the script.

```
$dir = "tokens/";
$fileNames = array_diff( scandir("data/"), array(".", "..") );

foreach($fileNames as $filename)
    if(file_exists($dir.$filename))
        exec("d:\mongodb\bin\mongoimport.exe -d import -c ".$filename." -f Date,Open,Next,Amount,Type --type csv --file ".$dir.$filename."");
```

I got around 7000 .csv files and it manage to insert only about 200 before script ends.

Can anyone help? I would appreciate any help

Comment: I can confirm that mongoimport doesn't work for some sparse csv files. They would load with errors and the result would have data in incorrect columns.  So, instead of figuring out what was happening I wrote a short program using an open source csv library to translate data from csv files to text files full of db.collection.insert() calls, one call per row of data. Although you can append many rows with a single insert call, it is better for error detection to do one row at a time.  The command files thus generated were processed using the mongo shell "mongo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing back end infrastructure.  It is just insane to try to load 7000 files into a database as part of a web request that is supposed to be short lived and is expected, by some of the software components as well as the end user, to only last a few seconds or maybe a minute.

Instead, create a backend service and command and control for this procedure.  In the web app, write each file name to be processed to a database table or even a plain text file on the server and then tell the end user that their request has been queued and will be processed within the next NN minutes.  Then have a cron job that runs every 5 minutes (or even 1 minute) that looks in the right place for stuff to do and can create reports of success or failure and/or send emails to tell the original requestor that it is done.

Comment: Thanks for reply to be more specific I need to load 7000 .csv files just once then part of files would be updated by few rows every day nothing intensive as trying to load 7000 files at once. But I need a way how to get them into DB. My web app would be calculating graphs and many others things for stock market in most of the operations big part of the data need to be read and there is posibility that it will be used by more people than just me. Can you suggest better solution for my problem?

Comment: This first step might be obvious, but you need to get all of the files onto the server using whatever you can, like copying to a USB drive that is taken to the server room, or remotely using FTP, or SCP.  Then, if you are going to use MongoDB you need to write a program or procedure to read each line of a CSV file and output the equivalent MongoDB db.collection.insert() statement.  Once you have that, you can run it on all of the CSV files using a loop of some kind.  On Linux in the shell this can be as easy as -- for f in *; do ( yourConverter <$f >$f.mongoDB ; mongo <$f.mongoDB ) ; done

Answer (score 0):

If this is intended as an import script and you are set on using PHP, it would be preferable to at least use the PHP CLI environment instead of performing this task through a web server. As it stands, it appears the CSV files are located on the server itself, so I see no reason to get HTTP involved. This would avoid an issue where the web request terminates and abruptly aborts the import process.

For processing the CSV, I'd start by looking at [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) or [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php). The [mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) command really does very little in the way of validation and sanitization. Parsing the CSV yourself will allow you to skip records that are missing fields, provide default values where necessary, or take other appropriate action. As you iterate through records, you can collect documents to insert in an array and then pass the results on to [MongoCollection::batchInsert()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.batchinsert.php) in batches. The driver will take care of splitting up large batches into chunks to actually send over the wire in 16MB messages (MongoDB's document size limit, which also applies to wire protocol communication).